# Match mixed data

Tags: google-sheets

In one column there are mixed sections, which are to be matched with data from other sheet. But as the sections format is different in entire column, not able to match

I have 2 sheets in which i have

Sheet 1   :

```
Column A         
AB-C,DE
```

Sheet 2  :

```
Column A    
ABCDE
```

I have to match this data in both the sheets

Comment: Can you add some more info or more data for us to better understand what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DitwunK00xSt1VmBOtCH6eWTWRHdR_QhhGbij0Vl5vM/edit?usp=sharing                                                                                                                                   I want to match data from sheet 1 and sheet 2

Comment: Hey can you provide some example in your sheet ? what do you want to match, data separated by commas ? full cell ? etc..

Comment: Full cell! Update sheet with example

Comment: Your data are very hard to work with ...  can you at least try to clean the file ? and add more than 1 example : It appears that you have some entries with several matches..

Comment: how do I separate text and numbers into multiple cells?

e.g in Cell A1 contains the following text
Nike Shoes 20 x 30  465784 

i would like the result to be
NIke Shoes in 1 cell, and the numbers separated into different cells.
20 in 1 cell
30 in next cell
465784 in next cell                                                                                                                                                      For that particular data, so that I can vlook up and match data in Sheet 2

Answer (score 1):

So my solution isn't perfect du to my limited knowledge in regular expression combined to the messy data.

First, extract the codes from `Sheet1!A:A`, replacing non digits with an emoji.

```
REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[^\d*]","️")
```

Then split each code to create an array

```
split(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[^\d*]","️"),"️",true,true)
```

Now we need to create a regex when we'll try to matches theses codes with `Sheet2`

```
"^"&textjoin("|-",true,split(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[^\d*]","️"),"️",true,true))&"-"
```

Now use this regex with `regexmatch` to find correct matches. This formula returns the row if `true`.

```
=ArayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(Sheet2!A3:A,"^"&textjoin("|-",true,split(REGEXREPLACE(A3,"[^\d*]","️"),"️",true,true))&"-"),row(Sheet2!A3:A),))
```

Finally `=textjoin` to display results in one cell :

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",true,
   ArrayFormula(
      if(
            REGEXMATCH(Sheet2!A2:A,"^"&textjoin("|-",true,split(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[^\d*]","️"),"️",true,true))&"-")
           ,row(Sheet2!A2:A),)
   )
)
```

Illustration :

[image]

Comment: @vaibhav jeevan dont forget to accept the answer thanks.